# Map html element to json object

Tags: javascript, json

I have an html element like this,

```
<div class='myparent'>
    <div>
        <div class="pdp-product-price">
            <span> 650 rupees</span>
            <div class="origin-block">
               <span> 1,500 rupees</span>
               <span>-57%</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to create a json of this 'myparent' div.

```
{
    "div": {
        "div": {
            "div": {
                "span": {},
                "div": {
                    "span": {},
                    "span": {}
                }
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Is there a way to do this in javascript?

Comment: it is bound to fail in the general case, consider having span,div,span having the same parent. The fact you are using object in json (instead of array) to represent them would only allow you to store two keys (span, div)

Comment: Check out https://azaslavsky.github.io/domJSON/

Comment: Do you really want to have repeated keys or do you want the children as an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive function that builds the json. To ensure no issues with the keys (that have a possibility to be duplicates) the following was added `:n` where `n` is the index of the element.

```js
function htmlToObject(targetElement) {
  return Array
    .from(targetElement.children)
    .reduce((acc, cur, i) => {
      acc[`${cur.tagName}:${i}`.toLowerCase()] = htmlToObject(cur);
      return acc;
    }, {});
}

const startElement = document.getElementsByClassName("myparent")[0];

const res = {
  [startElement.tagName.toLowerCase()]: htmlToObject(startElement)
};

console.log(res);
```

```html
<div class='myparent'>
  <div>
    <div class="pdp-product-price">
      <span> 650 rupees</span>
      <div class="origin-block">
        <span> 1,500 rupees</span>
        <span>-57%</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `children` property of [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children)

Then iterate over parent recursively and get subtree.

**But be aware that you cannot assign two values with the same key**. Therefore, you can use an index when assigning subtree like

```
  "div": {
     "span_1": {},
     "span_2": {},
  }
```

Hope the below snippet will give you a clue.

```js
const parent = document.getElementById('parent')

const tree = {};


const getTree = (elem) => {
   const subtree = {};
   for(let child of elem.children){
       subtree[child.tagName.toLowerCase()] = getTree(child)
   }
   return subtree;
}

tree[parent.tagName.toLowerCase()] = getTree(parent);

console.log(tree);
```

```html
<div id="parent" class='myparent'>
  <div>
    <div class="pdp-product-price">
      <span> 650 rupees</span>
      <div class="origin-block">
        <span> 1,500 rupees</span>
        <span>-57%</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```